# Spring: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions, for M-to-M

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My program has a user and a role configuration of security, two models that have between them a many-to-many relationship. When I am trying to save a new user and his m-to-m relationship in a separate table named "user_roles", I get the following error on the session.save() function:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : [com.session.library.libraryofbooks.model.Role.employees#1]
```

Here is my User model code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;


    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> employees = new HashSet<>();

}
```

UserRepository

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        User foundUser = (User) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).uniqueResult();
        return foundUser;
    }

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        session.save(user);
    }

}
```

UserService save user function:

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");

    Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
    roleSet.add(userRole);

    user.setRoles(roleSet);
    userRepo.saveUser(user);
}
```

And the RoleRepository

```
@Repository("roleRepository")
public class RoleRepository  {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public Role findByName(String name) {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Role.class);
        Role foundRole = (Role) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).uniqueResult();
        return foundRole;
    }

}
```

Neither the user datas and the role and the user ids from the user_role table are saving, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using @Transactional but then you use EM to open sessions (and never close it). You should get the current session (SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).

Anyway I would suggest you to use a pure JPA orm agnostic. 
SessionFactory is Hibernate's but you could just use JPA layer and forget about the ORM under the hood. 
If you go this way the modification would be:

```
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public Role findByName(String name) {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);  
            Root<Role> from = criteriaQuery.from(Role.class);
            Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get("name"), name);
            criteriaQuery.where(condition );
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
            Role foundRole = (Role) query.getSingleResult(); 
            return foundRole;
        }
```

a simplier approach:

```
        public Role findByName(String name) {
           TypedQuery<Role>query= entityManager.createQuery("Select r from Role r where name=:name",MyEntity.class);
           query.
           return query.setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult()
        }
```

Here you are another approach (cleaner from my point of view) to implement data access using jpa: 
https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitymanager-and-entitymanagerfactory-example-using-hibernate-with-persist-find-contains-detach-merge-and-remove